# wp_kses_allowed_html target in wordperss post context

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to allow target attribute in wordpress.

i used that code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', 'georgef_allow_anchor_target_attribute_in_post', 20, 2 );

function prefix_allow_anchor_target_attribute_in_post( $tags, $context ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $context, array( 'post' ) ) )
        return $tags;
    $tags['a']['target'] = true;
    return $tags;
}
```

I take it from [here](https://gist.github.com/GaryJones/7057100) with some adjustments.

I paste it as a Snippet i my wordpress site an get that error:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'georgef_allow_anchor_target_attribute_in_post' not found or invalid function name in public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298

Don't understand what is the problem.

thanks.

Comment: Fix your link in text.

Comment: thanks. fixed. @ravid

Answer (score 1):

prefix_allow_anchor_target_attribute_in_post and georgef_allow_anchor_target_attribute_in_post needs to be same.

So use

```
add_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', 'georgef_allow_anchor_target_attribute_in_post', 20, 2 );

function georgef_allow_anchor_target_attribute_in_post( $tags, $context ) {
     if ( ! in_array( $context, array( 'post' ) ) )
         return $tags;
     $tags['a']['target'] = true;
         return $tags;
}
```